# Failed to add the android platform

Tags: android, cordova

when trying to add android platform in this way.

cordova platform add android

Error: The command `android` failed. Make sure you Have the latest Android SDK installed, and the `android` command (inside the tools / folder) added to your path. Output: 

or

phonegap local run android 

phoonegapadding the android platform...
error An error occured android During creation of sub-project.

or

phonegap build android

phonegap detecting Android SDK environment...

phonegap using the local environment

phonegap adding the Android platform...

error An error occured android During creation of sub-project.

seems to have painted the variable path and I as follows. and it seems to me that this set correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your path is set wrong.

You currently have:

```
C:\Users\diseno\Downloads\adt-bundle;
```

It needs to be:

```
C:\Users\diseno\Downloads\adt-bundle\platform-tools;C:\Users\diseno\Downloads\adt-bundle\tools;
```

Double check to see if that is the right location of the `platform-tools` and `tools` folders. The solution is you need your path to be pointing to those folders (`platform-tools` and `tools`).

You can see so in the documentation listed at PhoneGap [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.8.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android)